# Does uncountable sets always have a countable dense subset?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I was thinking of $\mathbb{R}^n$ or like set of all continuous function on a closed bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. All these sets have a countable dense subset. Is this true for all sets?

If not I want to know an example s.t this does not hold.

Comment: What metric are you using on the function space in your second example?  It sounds like you are assuming continuous functions, otherwise this is not an example.

Comment: Yes I assumed that.

Comment: Even with continuous functions, if you use the discrete metric there is no countable dense subset.  You need to use something like the area between two functions to make there be a countable dense subset.  Each space has *lots* of topologies- often there is one that is standard, but you should specify it, particularly when looking for strange behavior.  Often some other topology will provide the strange behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is no. This is a very special property of topological spaces which are called seperable spaces. In example would be an uncountable metric space with the metric $$d(x,y)=\cases{0 \text{ if $x=y$}\\1 \text{ otherwise}.}$$ The topology induced by this metric is called discrete, and every subset of this space is both open and closed. Thus, the only set that is dense is the whole set itself, which we said was uncountable. A more interesting example is the [Long Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_(topology)), or the space of functions, [$L^\infty$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space).

Answer (score 2):

In general, the answer is no: consider the discrete topology on an uncountable set. :P A topological space with a countable dense subset is called *separable* (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_space); almost all spaces appearing "in nature" are separable.

Comment: I read that but I want an example.

Comment: @SubhasishBasak This is an example . . . in fact, exactly the same one Alex S gave.